# Google Map API - can't deleted marker in a for loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, for-loop

I populated a Google map with JSON data, i got some checkbox to choose what category of data to show on the map. 
When i click on the checkbox it's call a new JSON data through Ajax, when i uncheck a box it loops on the array of all markers and delete all the marker with the category unchecked.

It's works most of the time, but sometimes the marker disappear and appear again. It seems that they still in the array or something...

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).change(function() {
        var data ='';
        var checkbox = $(this);
        var checkboxVal = $(this).val();
        console.log('click');

        if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
            $('.loader').show();

            $("input:checkbox[name=poi_categories]:checked").each(function() {
                data = data + checkboxVal + ',';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: window.location.pathname,
                    data: "categorie=" + data,
                    success:function(response){

                        json = JSON.parse(response);

                        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                            createMarker(json[i], data);
                        }
                        $('.loader').hide();
                    }
                });
            });
        } else {

            for (var i in markersArray) {
                if ( markersArray[i] != undefined) {
                    if( null == markersArray[i].cat || markersArray[i].cat == checkboxVal) {
                        markersArray[i].setMap(null);
                        delete(markersArray[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    });
```

I'm pretty sure there is a mistake in the last for loop but i can't see what...

EDIT :

Here is the whole Js code : http://jsfiddle.net/5bMQm/

Comment: what does `createMarker` do exactly?

Comment: see update in the edited question

Comment: Same same :) The marker disappear one second and then appear again like if the `setMAp(null)`don't works

Comment: Yeah the `markerAray` can be biiiig like 900 items if the user like to check things :)

Comment: what about the markup / html? here forked http://jsfiddle.net/ZbZbM/ with google maps included as external resource

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I understand what you're trying to do now.

```
for (var i = 0, l = markersArray.length; i < l; i++) {
  if ( markersArray[i] != undefined) {
    if( null == markersArray[i].cat || markersArray[i].cat == checkboxVal) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
      markersArray.splice(i, 1);
      i--; l--;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `splice`works great on the array but the `setMap`seems not to work with it ?

Answer (score 1):

Totally misundersttod. You do this multiple times, each time the user click on a checkbox -- thats why you want to remove markers removed from the map from the markersArray also.

Think I have found the underlying problem.

You have

```
createMarker(json[i], data);
```

but only

```
function createMarker(marker) {
```

you set

```
cat : marker.img
```

but compare with

```
markersArray[i].cat == checkboxVal
```

which you assume (I guess) should contain

```
var checkboxVal = $(this).val();
..
data = data + checkboxVal + ',';
```

but never does! **data / checkboxval is never assigned to your marker!**

---

```
for (var i in markersArray) {
    if ( markersArray[i] != undefined) {
        if( null == markersArray[i].cat || markersArray[i].cat == checkboxVal) {
            markersArray[i].setMap(null);
            markersArray[i] = undefined; // <---
        }
    }
}
//cleanup
for (var i=markersArray.length;i>0;i--) {
    if (markersArray[i]==undefined]) {
        markersArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hum, still got the issue... Ok, looks loke it's the setMap is bugging no ?

Comment: absolutely not, done what you are trying to do a many, many times.

Answer (score 0):

*It's works most of the time, but sometimes the marker disappear and appear again. It seems that they still in the array or something*

Your code as it is works for me as expected, when everything works as expected.

But the issue(assuming the returned response of your serverside script is always correct):

You can't expect that the AJAX-responses arrive in the same order as they have been sended(there sometimes may be a huge delay for single requests). It may e.g. happen that you e.g.

1. click a box to check it
2. click the box again to uncheck it

When the responses arrive in reverse order you will create the markers although the box currently is not checked.

**Possible solution:**(but there is a better  one, see below )

Add an additionally check at the begin of `createMarker`

```
if(!$('input[type="checkbox"][name="poi_categories"][value="'+marker.img+'"]').is(':checked'))return;
```

Another issue: there seems to be a reduntant part in your script,

```
$("input:checkbox[name=poi_categories]:checked").each(function() {
  /*ajax-code*/
});
```

This doesn't make any sense to me, assuming you have checked 5 checkboxes and the last clicked checkbox has a value of e.g. "hotel", you will send `categories=hotel,hotel,hotel,hotel,hotel` , I don't think that your serverside script will return any marker for this. You don't need to iterate over the checked markers at all.

This should be sufficient:

```
if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
                $('.loader').show();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: window.location.pathname,
                        data: "categorie=" + checkboxVal,
                        success:function(response){

                            json = JSON.parse(response);

                            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                                createMarker(json[i], data);
                            }

                            $('.loader').hide();
                        }
                    });

            }
```

Here is a good point for the better solution to avoid the major issue. Instead of checking the checked-property of the checkbox before creating the marker, it would be better to abort the recent request:

```
    var checkbox = $(this);
    var checkboxVal = $(this).val();
    console.log('click');
    //if there has been a recent request, abort it
    if(checkbox.data('xhr')){
        checkbox.data('xhr').abort();console.log('recent request aborted');
    }
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
        $('.loader').show();

            data = data + checkboxVal + ',';
            //store the jqXhr within the checkbox-data
            //to be able to abort it later
            checkbox.data('xhr',$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: window.location.pathname,
                data: "categorie=" + checkboxVal,
                success:function(response){

                    json = JSON.parse(response);

                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        createMarker(json[i], data);
                    }

                    $('.loader').hide();
                }
            }));

    } else {/* your code*/}
```